# Iterated integrals agree and finite but double is infinite

Tags: real-analysis

What would be an example of $f$ s.t. $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f dx dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f dx dy < \infty$ but the double integral
$$\int_{[0,1]^2} f \ d(x,y) = \infty$$

Or maybe there doesn't exist such $f$ (which I doubt)? The integrals are Lebesgue.

Comment: an $f$ with (large) discontinuities inside the unit rectangle maybe?

Comment: What if $\int_0^1 f dx$ is actually always zero but only gets that way by "catastrophic cancellation". For example $f(x,y)=\operatorname{sign}(x-1/2)/(y-1/2)$. Or do you specifically want the double integral to be $+\infty$ rather than indeterminate? That much I suspect is impossible, since if the positive or negative part has finite integral, then I think you can "remove" it and then be able to apply Tonelli (and then Tonelli lets you apply Fubini).

Comment: I want the double integral to be $\infty$... Actually I would like to know if the two iterated integrals agree and are finite does that imply that the double integral is also finite?

Comment: @user16015: No, it does not. It can still happen that the double integral **does not exist at all**. But if you insist on the double integral having a definite value (even $\pm\infty$), then the iterated integrals will have the same value as (a slight modification) of my answer shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $f$ is measurable (otherwise the double integral does not make sense).

In this case, there is no counterexample, since your assumption on the double integral implies $\int_{[0,1]^2} f_+ d(x,y)=\infty$ and $\int_{[0,1]^2} f_- d(x,y)<\infty$ (where $f_+$ and $f_-$ denote the positive/negative parts of $f$).

But now, the Fubini-Tonelli theorem yields

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]} f_+ (x,y) \,dx\,dy =\infty\\
\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]} f_-(x,y) \,dx\,dy <\infty
\end{eqnarray*}
and analogously for the other ordering of integrals. In particular, the "inner" integral over $f_-$ is finite for almost all $y$.

Adding these two identities shows
$$
\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]} f(x,y) \, dy\, dx=\infty
$$
and likewise for the other ordering.